# 2.8 crashes when I render using GPU

Tags: rendering, gpu

I just started my journey with Blender, and started following some tutorials on YouTube. Here's my problem, I tried to change the render settings to GPU compute, but as soon as i hit "render", Blender crashes, without any message. I used 2.79, and today I wanted to see if the problem is still present in 2.8, and sadly it is. My GPU is a Radeon RX570, and I have the latest drivers. Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried running blender from cmd with the debugflag (-d) set? It would look similar to this, with your own paths of course: C:\Users\Constatin\blender2.8>blender -b C:\Users\Constatin\blendfolder\important2.blend -d. Normally there should then be an error message if blender crashes, which can guide your way

Comment: I think I solved the problem. My GPU was listed 2 times, and both were checked, so after i unchecked one, it seems to work. It is ok, or should be both checked?                https://imgur.com/VXLrCVM

Comment: Thats kind of a funny bug.. Maybe try a benchmark and compare your score to those with the same graphicscard or run a program to monitor GPU usage to make sure it is used

Comment: Yeah, haha. Funny thing, if I uncheck the first one and check the second, it crashes again. I can see that its working by looking at the render times